# How to combine two binary image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a final project in which I have to combine two images from optic disk segmentation and optic cup segmentation on binary images. I can't combine both images.
[image: Optik Disk]
[image: Optik Cup]

i wish anyone can help me. thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by combine? What outcome are you expecting?

Comment: This question has even less information than your last attempt, which was closed as unclear. Perhaps you should try clarifying your requirements and showing us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

If the images are binary, you may want to take the logical AND to get the pixels that are white in both of them.

```
im3=im1 & im2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two images have the same size and the values are in {0,1}, I think

```
result = image1 .* image2;
```

would be the most natural choice, yielding a result like this:
[image: result]